# How can we tune a simple select query with few conditions?

Tags: oracle

I have a query like below.

```
select col1,col2,col3,col4
from   table
where  CHANGETIME BETWEEN 0 AND 86399
AND    changedate+(changetime/86400) > To_Date('parameterised value','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
AND    CHANGEDATE >= trunc(To_Date('parameterised value','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
```

The query fetches records between 20000 to 50000 in prod environment. but still it takes minimum 50 minutes. sometimes it is taking 1 to 2 hours also. we have index on one column i.e CHANGEDATE . we have constraint like any new indexes cant be created. Please suggest how can we tune this query. Have used parallel hint also but not much improvement. Please suggest.

Comment: can you use SHOW PLAN and see the execution plan for this query ?

Comment: Cant share exactly the explain plan for it. But it is going for full table scan.

Comment: @RanjeetkumarNayak Try BETWEEN for the `changedate` column and see whether any improvement in the performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the query so the calculations are all done on the parameterised value so that the query can use the index on the columns (rather than requiring a function-based index):

```
select col1,col2,col3,col4
from   table
where  CHANGETIME BETWEEN 0 AND 86399
AND    CHANGETIME >  (  TO_DATE(:value,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                      - TRUNC(TO_DATE(:value,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))
                     ) * 86400
AND    CHANGEDATE >= TRUNC(TO_DATE(:value,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
```

or even:

```
select col1,col2,col3,col4
from   table
where  CHANGETIME
         BETWEEN (  TO_DATE(:value,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                  - TRUNC(TO_DATE(:value,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))
                 ) * 86400 + 1
         AND     86399
AND    CHANGEDATE >= TRUNC(TO_DATE(:value,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
```

Comment: Good basic advice that is often forgotten.

Comment: The description is well put.  Avoid the math on the table column.  Do the math on the parameter.  Use the column naturally in order to allow DB to optimize as needed, such as using an index.  This concept should be somewhere on this site as a best practice.

Comment: Thanks..it helped me in improving performance. with parallel processing and this idea. it showed improvement.